# Adding logout functionality to Flutter popup menu

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I want to implement logout functionality from a popup menu.  I have reviewed a lot of great answers on stackoverflow and checked the Flutter documentation but I have not been able to get my code to behave as I want.  When logout is clicked in the popup menu I want the user to be signed out and then returned to the landing page.  I have been able to implement that flow with a text button but I cannot figure out how to do it from within the popup menu.  The code I have written does not sign the user out so the user is taken to the landing page where the landing page correctly sees that the user is still logged in so it displays the Home page instead of the Landing page.  I think I am calling the confirmSignOut method from my Auth class incorrectly but as a beginner I can't figure it out after trying a lot of different approaches.  Clicking on any of the pop up menu items navigates the user to the correct page.  The FadeScale class within the Navigator is just a custom animated transition I use instead of the standard Material page route transition.  I can add the code for the FadeScale class if that is helpful in answering the question.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
class BrandPopUpMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  const BrandPopUpMenu({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopupMenuButton<String>(
      onSelected: (value) {
        switch (value) {
          case PopUpMenuText.settings:
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              FadeScaleRoute(
                widget: const SettingsPage(),
              ),
            );
            break;
          case PopUpMenuText.search:
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              FadeScaleRoute(
                widget: const MainSearchPage(),
              ),
            );
            break;
          case PopUpMenuText.help:
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              FadeScaleRoute(
                widget: const HelpCenterPage(),
              ),
            );
            break;
          case PopUpMenuText.logout:
            Auth().confirmSignOut(context);
            Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
              FadeScaleRoute(
                widget: const LandingPage(),
              ),
              (Route route) => false,
            );
            break;
        }
      },
      itemBuilder: (context) => PopUpMenuText.items
          .map(
            (item) => PopupMenuItem<String>(
              value: item,
              child: Text(
                item,
              ),
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}

abstract class AuthBase {
  User? get currentUser;
  Stream<User?> authStateChanges();
  Future<User?> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
  Future<User?> signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
  Future<User?> signInAnonymously();
  Future<User?> signInWithGoogle();
  Future<void> confirmSignOut(BuildContext context);
  Future<void> signOut();
}

class Auth implements AuthBase {
  final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  User? get currentUser => _firebaseAuth.currentUser;

  @override
  Stream<User?> authStateChanges() => _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges();

  @override
  Future<User?> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    String email,
    String password,
  ) async {
    final userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
    return userCredential.user;
  }

  @override
  Future<User?> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    String email,
    String password,
  ) async {
    final userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(
      EmailAuthProvider.credential(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      ),
    );
    return userCredential.user;
  }

  @override
  Future<User?> signInAnonymously() async {
    final userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously();
    return userCredential.user;
  }

  @override
  Future<User?> signInWithGoogle() async {
    final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    if (googleUser != null) {
      final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
      if (googleAuth.idToken != null) {
        final userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(
          GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
            idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
            accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
          ),
        );
        return userCredential.user;
      } else {
        throw FirebaseAuthException(
          code: FirebaseExceptionString.missingGoogleIDTokenCode,
          message: FirebaseExceptionString.missingGoogleIDTokenMessage,
        );
      }
    } else {
      throw FirebaseAuthException(
        code: FirebaseExceptionString.abortedByUserCode,
        message: FirebaseExceptionString.canceledByUserMessage,
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> _signOut(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      final auth = Provider.of<AuthBase>(
        context,
        listen: false,
      );
      await auth.signOut();
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<dynamic>(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => const LandingPage(),
        ),
        (route) => false, //Setting to false disables the back button
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(
        e.toString(),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> confirmSignOut(BuildContext context) async {
    final didRequestSignOut = await showAlertDialog(
      context,
      cancelActionText: DialogString.cancel,
      content: DialogString.signOutAccount,
      defaultActionText: DialogString.signOut,
      title: DialogString.signOut,
    );
    if (didRequestSignOut == true) {
      _signOut(context);
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> signOut() async {
    final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    await googleSignIn.signOut();
    await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
}
```

Comment: `confirmSignOut` is an `async` method, but you do not use `await` on it when you call it from the dropdown menu button. So navigation will likely be executed when sign out is not completed yet.

Comment: Peter Koltai. You are absolutely correct and now it works perfectly.  I cannot thank you enough.

Comment: Good to hear, welcome!